# Understanding SPF fails for email sent

Tags: email-server, spf

I'm trying to get my head around this issue. My emails are getting sent into spam for people. In this case, its gmail. If I look at the email details I get:

[image]

109.74.201.130 is another server, which hosts **ultranerds.co.uk**. This is the SPF record I have for the domain **clickpress.com**:

[image]

...and here are the email details I'm sending:

```
From: editor@clickpress.com
Subject: Your ClickPress news release has been approved
To: andy@ultranerds.co.uk
```

So why on earth is it trying to lookup the IP for ultranerds.co.uk, and doing the SPF check on that? I thought the whole point of SPF was that it looks up the SENDERs info, not the RECIPIENT???  (I've never seen this behaviour before)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah man - I just realised what it was! I'm sending to my email on ultranerds, but that is actually a forwarder to my gmail account. So what it's doing it checking the IP of the forwarding server, not the originating. Duh!

Comment: Do mark your answer as the correct answer...

Comment: @ChristopherH yup will do (it won't let me do it for 2 days though). I was half tempted to delete my question, but thought I'd leave it up there in case it helps someone else in the future

Comment: Yeah, that’s generally what you should do - no matter how silly or stupid you think your question is, your hours of pain can spare someone else going through the same.